# Where can one download a legal copy of Windows 10 Enterprise or Education?

Tags: windows-10, applocker

I’m trying to set up a single office PC for a small business. I need to lock it down with the [AppLocker](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/124008-use-applocker-allow-block-executable-files-windows-10-a.html). But it seems like Windows 10 Pro doesn’t support it and only “Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education” does.

I checked online and, I'm probably not doing something right, but I can't find them online. The only place I can download them is via a torrent site.

So, where can I legally download/purchase a single copy of “Windows 10 Enterprise” or “Windows 10 Education?” All I need it for is to use the AppLocker.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t see anything suggesting AppLocker is only available on Win 10 enterprise or education. That can be seen here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/requirements-to-use-applocker

What I do see is that you can only manage AppLocker policies via Group Policy on those versions of Windows 10. Otherwise, it is available but needs to be configured via MDM or Powershell as documented here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/use-the-applocker-windows-powershell-cmdlets

Comment: Did anyone try it? I can't make it work on Win10 Pro.

Comment: @c00000fd sorry. I can’t find any definitive information about what features of AppLocker are supported on which version of Windows. AppLocker is available on Win 10 pro and you can manage the policies with group policy. I’ve seen it. But even the links that are supposed to tell you what features are supported within those pages take you nowhere useful. You’ll just have to try it. Open gpedit.msc and go to computer settings - windows settings - security settings - application control policies - AppLocker.

Comment: I did try it all. I can set it all up in the gpedit.msc (or via the power shell) and even start the App identity service vie the net command. It's just that nothing is enforced by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade any installed version of Windows 10 to any higher licence simply by installing the appropriate licence key.

However, you won't get licence keys for Windows 10 Education unless you're a qualifying educational establishment, and Windows 10 Enterprise licences are only available through Microsoft's volume licenceing program, or their authorised partners. If you're an individual you're probably out of luck.

Comment: hahaha. Thank you. Reminds me of a Marijuana license/stamp that was required by the US Government (back in the day) -- "pot was legal for as long as you had a stamp for it. But the federal government was not issuing any stamps."

Answer (score 0):

To get any copy of Windows 10, you have to use the Media Creation Tool. You can download it directly from Windows, and run the .exe, and you can either make an ISO to burn using Rufus, or you can make installation media directly using it.

However, HeiDoc provides a Windows ISO downloader that fetches links from Microsoft’s TechBench site (the official Microsoft replacement for its former Digital River site) and downloads the ISOs. I’d recommend this latter method because it’s faster. You can burn the ISO downloaded using Rufus later.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise licenses can be purchased through Microsoft's volume licensing program. You should be able to purchase these from any of Microsoft's partners however you will be required to buy 5 licenses at minimum.

Education licenses can be obtained in a similar manner but you're company will have to qualify as an eligible academic institution.

Once you've made the purchase you will receive a document with a Authorization number and agreement number that can be used to setup a Microsoft VLSC account which is where you can access your licenses and ISOs.

Comment: And then they wonder why people torrent software :)